# 60's 3-pt serial about a boy who finds an alien ship at stonehenge

Tags: story-identification

My father recently told me when he was a young boy in the 60's he read 2 parts of a 3 part serial in a magazine similar to, and possibly even, Analog, in which a boy finds an alien ship buried under stonehenge. He gets in the ship and it is programmed to return to its home planet. He said that all these years later, he would love to find out what happened, but in the literally thousands of sci-fi works he's come across that is one that has escaped him. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/206782/science-fiction-story-where-an-older-person-alien-is-barricaded-in-a-house-and (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

Aha! [A Trace of Memory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1612870112) by Keith Laumer.

One of the Amazon reviews mentions it was

> originally serialized in *Amazing* in 1962 and published in book form
>   the following year.

The [Goodreads description](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1549260.A_Trace_of_Memory) includes this blurb:

> Foster has hired Legion to help him regain his lost memory. Then both
>   men are suddenly attacked by alien powers. They flee to Stonehenge in
>   England where they discover a strange control chamber deep in the
>   ruins.

And [here's a review](http://www.sffworld.com/book/1395.html) mentioning the spaceship under Stonehenge aspect and returning to the home planet.